# Android custom fonts - for system components like Actionbar, Toast, Dialogs

Tags: android, fonts

I am working on application translated to languages that are not supported - missing fonts on devices.
So I added fonts to application and changed typeface for all TextViews, EditTexts, Buttons.
Also I was able to change fonts in WebView. 
But now I need to change typeface for all system components:

1. ActionBar:

   - Title Dropdown
   - Menu
   - ShareActionProvider
   - ActionItems
   - ActionItems in  overflow
2. Dialog
3. Toast
4. Settings Screen

Is there a way to change typeface for this components. 
Probably all have some TextView in them - just to know their id to find them.

Please do not post answers about changing Typeface on TextView!

Comment: I think you should use style, and theme read here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: Can you give me an example? I did not find any way to change custom fonts by style - only programatically

Answer (score 2):

Create Views with custom fonts like this

**FontManager.java**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.InflateException;

public class FontManager
{
    //Making FontManager a singleton class
    private static class InstanceHolder
    {
        private static final FontManager INSTANCE = new FontManager();
    }

    public static FontManager getInstance()
    {
        return FontManager.InstanceHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    private FontManager()
    {
    }

    // Different tags used in XML file.
    private static final String TAG_FAMILY = "family";
    private static final String TAG_NAMESET = "nameset";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_FILESET = "fileset";
    private static final String TAG_FILE = "file";

    // Different styles supported.
    private static final String STYLE_BOLD = "-Bold.ttf";
    private static final String STYLE_ITALIC = "-Italic.ttf";
    private static final String STYLE_BOLDITALIC = "-BoldItalic.ttf";

    private class FontStyle
    {
        int style;
        Typeface font;
    }

    private class Font
    {
        // different font-family names that this Font will respond to.
        List<String> families;

        // different styles for this font.
        List<FontStyle> styles;
    }

    private List<Font> mFonts;

    //private boolean isFamilySet = false;
    private boolean isName = false;
    private boolean isFile = false;

    // Parse the resId and initialize the parser.
    public void initialize(Context context, int resId)
    {
        XmlResourceParser parser = null;
        try
        {
            parser = context.getResources().getXml(resId);
            mFonts = new ArrayList<Font>();

            String tag;
            int eventType = parser.getEventType();

            Font font = null;

            do
            {
                tag = parser.getName();

                switch ( eventType )
                {
                    case XmlPullParser.START_TAG:
                        if ( tag.equals(TAG_FAMILY) )
                        {
                            // one of the font-families.
                            font = new Font();
                        }
                        else if ( tag.equals(TAG_NAMESET) )
                        {
                            // a list of font-family names supported.
                            font.families = new ArrayList<String>();
                        }
                        else if ( tag.equals(TAG_NAME) )
                        {
                            isName = true;
                        }
                        else if ( tag.equals(TAG_FILESET) )
                        {
                            // a list of files specifying the different styles.
                            font.styles = new ArrayList<FontStyle>();
                        }
                        else if ( tag.equals(TAG_FILE) )
                        {
                            isFile = true;
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                        if ( tag.equals(TAG_FAMILY) )
                        {
                            // add it to the list.
                            if ( font != null )
                            {
                                mFonts.add(font);
                                font = null;
                            }
                        }
                        else if ( tag.equals(TAG_NAME) )
                        {
                            isName = false;
                        }
                        else if ( tag.equals(TAG_FILE) )
                        {
                            isFile = false;
                        }
                        break;

                    case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                        String text = parser.getText();
                        if ( isName )
                        {
                            // value is a name, add it to list of family-names.
                            if ( font.families != null )
                                font.families.add(text);
                        }
                        else if ( isFile )
                        {
                            // value is a file, add it to the proper kind.
                            FontStyle fontStyle = new FontStyle();
                            fontStyle.font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), text);

                            if ( text.endsWith(STYLE_BOLD) )
                                fontStyle.style = Typeface.BOLD;
                            else if ( text.endsWith(STYLE_ITALIC) )
                                fontStyle.style = Typeface.ITALIC;
                            else if ( text.endsWith(STYLE_BOLDITALIC) )
                                fontStyle.style = Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC;
                            else
                                fontStyle.style = Typeface.NORMAL;

                            font.styles.add(fontStyle);
                        }
                }

                eventType = parser.next();

            }
            while ( eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT );

        }
        catch ( XmlPullParserException e )
        {
            throw new InflateException("Error inflating font XML", e);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            throw new InflateException("Error inflating font XML", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( parser != null )
                parser.close();
        }
    }

    public Typeface get(String family, int style)
    {
        for ( Font font : mFonts )
        {
            for ( String familyName : font.families )
            {
                if ( familyName.equals(family) )
                {
                    // if no style in specified, return normal style.
                    if ( style == -1 )
                        style = Typeface.NORMAL;

                    for ( FontStyle fontStyle : font.styles )
                    {
                        if ( fontStyle.style == style )
                            return fontStyle.font;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**res/values/Fonts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Fonts">
        <!-- using android's -->
        <attr name="android:textStyle" />
        <!-- our custom attribute -->
        <attr name="font" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**res/xml/fonts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<familyset>

    <!-- Arial -->
    <family>
        <nameset>
            <name>Arial</name>
        </nameset>

        <fileset>
            <file>fonts/Arial-Regular.ttf</file>
            <file>fonts/Arial-Bold.ttf</file>
            <file>fonts/Arial-Italic.ttf</file>
            <file>fonts/Arial-BoldItalic.ttf</file>
        </fileset>
    </family>

</familyset>
```

Add the fonts inside **assets/fonts**

```
Arial-Bold.ttf
Arial-BoldItalic.ttf
Arial-Italic.ttf
Arial-Regular.ttf
```

Create your custom view ***Ex***: **FontableTextView.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class FontableTextView extends TextView
{
    private static final String TAG = "FontableTextView";

    public FontableTextView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public FontableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    public FontableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setCustomFont(context, attrs);
    }

    /* 
     * @see android.widget.CompoundButton#onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        // Fonts work as a combination of particular family and the style. 
        TypedArray a = ctx.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Fonts);
        String family = a.getString(R.styleable.Fonts_font);
        int style = a.getInt(R.styleable.Fonts_android_textStyle, -1);
        a.recycle();
        // Set the typeface based on the family and the style combination.
        if ( family != null )
        {
            setTypeface(FontManager.getInstance().get(family, style));
        }
    }
}
```

**Initiate FontManager to set custom fonts at the start of the MainActivity**

```
FontManager.getInstance().initialize(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.fonts);
```

**Use the custom view in Layout XML**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <com.package.FontableTextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:text="FontableTextView"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        custom:font="Arial" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. for actionbar:

use actionbar sherlock (http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and customize its code:

in com.actionbarsherlock.app.Actionbar add these two abstract methods:

```
public abstract void setTitleTypeface(Typeface TF);
public abstract void setSubtitleTypeface(Typeface TF);
```

and override these methods in com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarImpl

```
@Override
public void setTitleTypeface(Typeface TF) {
    mActionView.setTitleTypeface(TF);     }

@Override
public void setSubtitleTypeface(Typeface TF) {
    mActionView.setSubtitleTypeface(TF);    }
```

and also in com.actionbarsherlock.internal.app.ActionBarWrapper like this

```
@Override
public void setTitleTypeface(Typeface TF) {}
@Override
public void setSubtitleTypeface(Typeface TF) {}
```

and finally in com.actionbarsherlock.internal.widget.ActionBarView add these methods:

```
 public void setTitleTypeface(Typeface TF){
    mTitleView.setTypeface(TF);
}

public void setSubtitleTypeface(Typeface TF){
    mSubtitleView.setTypeface(TF);
}
```

and now use it in your SherlockActivity like this:

```
    Typeface TF = Typeface.createFromAsset(getApplication().getAssets(),
                "Arial.ttf");
    getSupportActionBar().setTitleTypeface(TF);
```

**Make Sure there is no better way!!!**

**2. for dialogs, system settings,... u should change code like this!**

Comment: actionbarsherlock is NOT a system component.

Comment: i did NOT say thats a system component!

Comment: the question was about system components.

Comment: but it's a replacement for ActionBar system component!