# what should be the address when running the appengine on localhost using android device and "Not Emulator"

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)

.setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")

Comment: Welcome to the site @kapsid. Could you tidy this question up a bit please? Each question and answer is intended to be a resource for other people too.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061646/3364266 Check this. It may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the internal ip address of the machine which is running the appengine server and you have to put the following line to your gradle build file of your appengine project

```
appengine {
 .....
 httpAddress = '0.0.0.0'
 ......
}
```