# Why don't default text sizes change per screen size, i.e on tablet?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, responsive, android-toast, text-size

I am making my app responsive, I am changing my font sizes accordingly, using the smallest width files.

I am finding it hard to believe that default text sizes for built in tools such as `AlertDialog`, `Toast`, `Menu` etc. don't change automatically. Especially since changing those texts are done programmaticly (besides menu which I modified in styles).

Am I missing something? Can Toast and dialog fonts also be changed in styles?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16061646/3364266 check this link. this might help you.

Comment: yes they can also be changed but you will have to make custom everything. follow above link it will surely help you

Comment: @Sharone Lev Have you tried to change text size of **Toast** and **Alert dialog**??

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati yes I can change them programmaticaly, but I am wishing for a more simple approach such as changing it in styles and I think this is something that should happen automatically when using larger screen size since these are Android built in features

Comment: @SharoneLev  if you just want to change text size in a simple way,why dont you try to make one utils method and use that.have you tried it?  it is as simple as style..

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati That's what I'm doing. But still, I need to call the method from every relevant place and I need to find out how to change each one of these elements. For instance, I managed to change the text size in dialog, but the buttons text size in the dialog don't change.. I changed the menu items size, but need to change the action bar... These are things you are not likely to touch when just programming for a phone, but on Tablet they appear too small in my opinion.

Comment: @SharoneLev so for Dialog use custom layout.and check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47524010/can-we-make-one-layout-type-for-all-screen-size/47524265#47524265)..